# WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session webdriver new session JSON response body did not contain a session ID

Tags: selenium-grid

I am using selenium grid with 1 hub and 2 node, When i am executing script getting this error:
rg.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session webdriver new session JSON response body did not contain a session ID
Command duration or timeout: 509 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.42.0', revision: '5e824302019c86eae9c8c3ca9155e7307b410cf8', time: '2014-05-24 09:48:41'
System info: host: 'WIN-PNKGI9TOHPD', ip: '192.168.1.206', os.name: 'Windows Server 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.7.0_55'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.

I am using POM structue.
here is my Json node congif file:

{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "chrome",
          "maxInstances": 2,
      "node": "b"
        },
        {
          "browserName": "firefox",
          "maxInstances": 2
        },
        {
          "browserName": "internet explorer",
          "maxInstances": 1

```
    }
  ],
"configuration":
    {
    "nodeTimeout":1200000,
    "port":5555,

    "hubPort":4444,
    "hubHost":"http://192.168.1.206",

    "nodePolling":2000,

    "registerCycle":10000,
    "register":true,
    "cleanUpCycle":2000,
    "timeout":50000,
    "maxSession":5,
    }
```